# AWS Cognito substitute on Pivotal Cloud Foundry (PCF)

Tags: amazon-cognito, cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa, pcfdev

I'm exploring Pivotal Cloud Foundry (PCF)'s PAS for moving our organisation's on-premise application onto private cloud. Going by the documentation, I'm unable to find if PCF has any offering for end user authentication & authorisation like we have Cognito on AWS?

If not, are there any other external service that can be used in conjunction with PCF for the purpose?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it'll be an exact replacement, but Pivotal Cloud Foundry has a single sign-on option available.

https://docs.pivotal.io/p-identity/1-6/index.html

It uses the same UAA, which comes with the platform and controls access to the platform, but is completely separate and allows you to provide similar access controls to your applications running on top of Pivotal Cloud Foundry.